# Images and Text in Unordered List not on the same line

Tags: html, css

so for some reason when I have these icons and this div positioned at the top right of the screen, the images and the div that'll contain the system time aren't resting on the same line together. Not really too sure why.

I've tried messing around with the margin settings of the list items because I've seen that the list items themselves have a weird margin that affects their height whilst the actual images themselves do not have this issue. Setting display to inline did not work.

```css
body {
  /* background-color: rgb(8, 5, 32); */
  background-image: url(https://512pixels.net/downloads/macos-wallpapers/10-14-Night.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

#system-time {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.863);
  font-family: 'SF Pro Display';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.nav-list img {
  filter: invert(100%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  width: 18px;
  height: auto;
  /* border: 2px solid; */
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>luke's desktop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles\style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg/2048px-Speaker_Icon.svg.png" href=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Globe_icon.svg/2048px-Globe_icon.svg.png" href=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1841400-200.png" href=""></li>
      <li>Tue 9 Jan 20:18</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="login">
      <div id="profile-pic">
        <img src="assets/dp.jpg" width="180px" height="180px">
        <div id="username">User</div>
      </div>

      <form id="passwordForm">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">

      </form>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Images don't have `href`, links do.

Comment: @Paulie_D added a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flexbox` on the `ul` rather than `display: inline-block` on the `li`.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(8, 5, 32);
}

#system-time {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'SF Pro Display';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-list li {
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.nav-list img {
  filter: invert(100%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  width: 18px;
  height: auto;
  /* border: 2px solid; */
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg/2048px-Speaker_Icon.svg.png"></li>
    <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Globe_icon.svg/2048px-Globe_icon.svg.png"></li>
    <li><img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1841400-200.png"></li>
    <li id="system-time">Tue 9 Jan 20:18</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```